# How to install `graphicx` package on my Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: installing

How to install `graphicx` package on my Ubuntu 15.04?

I think I need to install it since I get this error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `grapthicx.sty' not found.
```

when I use:

```
\usepackage{grapthicx}
\graphicspath{ {Home/Desktop/Fig/} }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! The package is called `graphicx`: your error suggests you have a typo (`grapthicx`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you simply did a typing error. The package is called `graphicx`, while you have written `grapthicx`, with an extra `t`!

Comment: This is basically the same what Joseph's comment said some minutes earlier ;-)

Comment: Didn't see it in time, sorry! Should I delete my answer? I'm quite a newbie here, thank you!

Comment: Nope, unless nobody flags it, it's ok. (I won't flag it ;-)) It's an answer anyway ;-)

Comment: yaaap, it's because of the "t" !!!
sorry for taking your time on a stupid thing like that